# How to return control form exec?

Tags: c, exec, system-calls

This is my code:

```
void function_exists(int foo)
{
    char bar[10] = "/bin/";
    int baz;
    strncat(bar,act_arg[0],sizeof(act_arg[0]));
    if(fork() == 0)
    {
        printf("\n");
        baz = execlp(bar,act_arg[0],NULL);
        if(baz == -1)
        {
            foo++;
            wait(NULL);
        }
        else
        {
            wait(NULL);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("Hello");
}
```

i am trying to return the control from execlp and i know that it does not return a value unless there is an error so i used a fork.But when i execute the code hello is printed first.Why is that happening?

And

is there a way i could make exec return or any other system call that does the same thing for me.Right now i press enter and the my program takes over but i want to do this without having to press enter.

I do not have enough rep to post images so here is a link to my output:
http://tinypic.com/r/6szw52/5

Comment: You could try popen() instead of exec.

Comment: I looked into it and found a place i could make use of this so thank q sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call *execlp* child process area will be overwritten by *execlp*, So code available after **execlp** will not executed.

Put *wait* in main loop you can achieve the desired result.

Examine this code you will get more idea.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pid_t child;
  child = fork();
  if(child == 0) {
    printf("at child\n");
        execlp("./hello",argv[0],NULL);
    printf("after execlp in child\n\n");
    sleep(2);
  }
  else {
    wait(NULL);
    printf("parrent finish\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

*printf* available after execlp will not execute.